# Cannot display data from database

Tags: mysql, perl, xhtml

I am writing a Perl program to insert name and age information into a MySQL table and display the current contents of this table.

This is the XHTML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head>
    <title>Perl Database Interfaces</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <form action="/cgi-bin/10.pl" method="post">
      <p> <b>Enter Your Information</b> <br /> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
        Age: <input type="text" name="age" /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p> 
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI ':standard';

print "content-type:text/html\n\n";

use DBI;

$dbh  = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:Temp", "root", "" );
$name = param( "name" );
$age  = param( "age" );

$sql  = "insert into Students values ('$name','$age')";
$sth  = $dbh->prepare( "$sql" );
$sth->execute;

$sql = "select * from Students";
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute;

print "<table border size=1>  <tr> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Age</th> </tr> ";

while ( ( $name, $age ) = $sth->fetchrow() ) {
    print "<tr> 
    <td>$name</td> 
    <td>$age</td>
     </tr> ";
}

$sth->finish();

$dbh->disconnect();

print "</table>";
```

The data is getting inserted into the database (I manually checked it using the terminal), but the data isn't displaying on the web browser. The table heading is displayed but not the rows. See the output I am getting

[image: 1]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code, but the specific thing that you're asking about is that statement handles don't have a method called `fetchrow`.

Comment: Any Perl code written in the last 10 years needs to have `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top.

Comment: okay. can you please tell what i can use instead of fetchrow() ?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI

Comment: `fetchrow_array`? `fetchrow_arrayref`? `fetchrow_hashref`? `fetchall_arrayref`? They're all in the DBI documentation, which you would know if you had bothered to read it!

Comment: I jstarted learning perl just 2 days ago. I just replaced fetchrow() with fetchrow_array still it isn't working.  @MattJacob

Comment: Part of learning a language is learning how to find the documentation for it, and DBI's is some of the best. What do the logs say?

Comment: Global symbol "$variables" requires explicit package name http://prntscr.com/dewnaq @MattJacob

Comment: That's not the same code you posted here...

Comment: The variable names and database are changed that's it. Everything else is same. The current code which i am running is here http://prntscr.com/dewpz6   Only the display from database isn't working, everything else is fine. @MattJacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:", undef, undef, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    PrintError => 0,
});

$dbh->do(q{
    create table students (
        name varchar(255),
        age int
    )
});

my $name = param("name");
my $age  = param("age");
$dbh->do(q{insert into students values (?, ?)}, undef, $name, $age);

print header();
print <<'EOF';
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
EOF

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select name, age from students});
$sth->execute;

while (($name, $age) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print <<EOF;
  <tr>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td>$age</td>
  </tr>
EOF
}

print qq~</table>\n~;
```

#### Command Line

```
$ perl 40949974.pl 'name=John Smith&age=30'
```

#### Output

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Explanation

By using an in-memory SQLite database and supplying the CGI parameters via the command line, we have a complete, self-contained example. For inserts, you don't really need the `prepare`/`execute` cycle unless you're inserting a bunch of records (in a loop, for example). I also used placeholders and bind values for the insert, which properly escapes your variables for you. However, if you're accepting user input via a web page, you'll want to do additional validation as well.

You can read the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) to find out more about any of these concepts.